# Uninstall softwares one after another using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to uninstall two software's based on completion of first uninstaller. Mean to say , I don't want to start second uninstaller until we complete the first uninstaller.

Can anyone please suggest me how can I achieve this scenario.

This is what I followed now.

**uninstall.sh:**

```
if [ $exitval -eq 0 ] then 
    ./uninstall1.sh
else
    echo uninstall1.sh else loop
fi

result=$?

if [ $result -eq 0 ]
    ./uninstall2.sh
else
    echo uninstall2.sh else loop
fi
```

Here the issue is , **uninstaller1** will launch one UI. Before completion of uninstaller1, **uninstaller2** UI will get launch. This is what I don't want.

Want to launch uninstall2 when uninstall1 gets finish.

**Update** : After goggling came to know that we can achieve this by using **wait** command. But, still struggling with the same issue .

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Those scripts probably run some process on the background. Can you show some of their contents?

Comment: Its not showing any text info, here just two uninstall UIs will get launch parallel. Here we are not waiting for uninstall 1 to get finish.

Comment: Saw your edit just now. The reason I was asking for the contents was to know how those parallel stuffs gets launched as to get the PID of the crucial program, you'd have to know it.

Answer (score 1):

Anyhow I'd just post my pending suggestion:

```
SomeLauncher1.sh

PID=$!  ## Not really the way to do it but this is one way how.

while kill -s 0 "$PID"; do  ## If true, process is still running.
    sleep 1s  ## Keep waiting.
done

SomeLauncher2.sh

... ## Perhaps do the same thing again.
```